# php data respond not returned

Tags: php, jquery

I'm still new in JQuery and Php.
I'm trying to create a simple sign up form that connect to signup.php file

Here's the JQuery :

```
        <!-- jQuery Here -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").click(function(){
        var fullname=$("#fullname").val();
        var email=$("#email").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        var dataString="fullname="+fullname+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&signup=";
        if($.trim(fullname).length>0 & $.trim(email).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/signup.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(html){
                    if(html=="success") { // display if success
                        alert("Thank you for Registering with us! you can login now");
                    }
                    else if(html=="exist") { // display if exist
                        alert("Hey! You alreay has account! you can login with us");
                    }
                    else if(html=="failed") {//display if failed
                        alert("Something Went wrong");
                    }
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
    <!-- end here -->
```

Here's the php :

```
<?php
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing connection with server
$db = mysql_select_db("try", $connection); // Selecting Database

if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $fullname=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fullname'])));
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])));
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password'])));
    $login=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from `phonegap_login` where `email`='$email'"));
    if($login!=0) {
        echo "exist"; // return if exist
    }
    else {
        $date=date("d-m-y h:i:s");
        $q=mysql_query("insert into `phonegap_login` (`reg_date`,`fullname`,`email`,`password`) values           ('$date','$fullname','$email','$password')");

        if($q) {
            echo "success"; // return if success
        }
        else {
            echo "failed"; // return if failed
        }
    }
    echo mysql_error();
}
mysql_close ($connection); // close connection
?>
```

The problem now is i did add the data to database, but i cant get the echo return back to my JQuery hence it wont display the results.

Any Answer will be appreciate.

Comment: are you certain the php has the correct data from the database, before trying to get it back to the jquery? var_dump() is your friend..

Comment: also, console.log(html) in your ajax success function.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `htmlspeciachars` when storing into the DB. That's intended for when you display text in web pages.

Comment: I might recommend using `json_encode()` in your PHP and transmit an object back, this way you can store the error and error status in two different variables. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Is it alerting anything at all? If not, maybe your script is getting an error. Check your PHP error log. And get rid of the `@` that disables warnings.

Comment: `console.log(html)` to see what you ACTUALLY got back. any php warnings/errors will become PART of the output, and make your string matches to fail.

Comment: in my `console.log(html)` i got this message
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/signup.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`